# AWS Lambda cannot Scan DyanmoDB table even when granted Read & Write permissions

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

My whole solution (infrastructure code and the actual lambda) are all [open-source](https://github.com/jwankhalaf/bash-todo).

Basically, I want a Go lambda that when called would query a dynamodb table and get all items. I know the `Scan` method is dangerous on DynamoDB (imagine you had 1000s of table items), but I know I only have 3 items in the table and this whole project is just an exercise in AWS CDK (Go) for me.

When I deploy my infrastructure with `cdk deploy --profile personal`, all is deployed without any issues.

However, when I try to call the the lambda URL, I simply get a `null` back.

[image]

When I check the CloudWatch logs, I can see an error, and the error message says that my lambda does not have permissions to do a Scan on my DynamoDB table! At least that's my understanding of the error message:

> 2022/09/11 15:32:30 could not scan the dyanmodb table! error: operation error DynamoDB: Scan, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 8JTBR7LIJ6H6UERR0NSM1U28EBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::777650698697:assumed-role/GoTodoAppStack-FunctionServiceRole675BB04A-VIK6COW772H2/GoTodoAppStack-Function76856677-333lC1zqdKCi is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:777650698697:table/GoTodoAppStack-tasks86073811-5DY3UBZUCHI6 because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:Scan action

If you take a close look at the [`cdk.go`](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/bash-todo/blob/main/cdk/cdk.go) file, you'll notice that I am granting my lambda read and write permissions to the dynamodb table.

```
// create a dynamodb table to store the tasks
table := awsdynamodb.NewTable(stack, jsii.String("tasks"), &awsdynamodb.TableProps{
    PartitionKey: &awsdynamodb.Attribute{
        Name: jsii.String("task_id"),
        Type: awsdynamodb.AttributeType_STRING},
    BillingMode:         awsdynamodb.BillingMode_PAY_PER_REQUEST,
    TimeToLiveAttribute: jsii.String("time_to_live"),
})

// add a global secondary index based on user_id
table.AddGlobalSecondaryIndex(&awsdynamodb.GlobalSecondaryIndexProps{
    IndexName:    jsii.String("user-index"),
    PartitionKey: &awsdynamodb.Attribute{Name: jsii.String("user_id"), Type: awsdynamodb.AttributeType_STRING},
    SortKey:      &awsdynamodb.Attribute{Name: jsii.String("created_at"), Type: awsdynamodb.AttributeType_STRING},
})

// bundling options to make go fast
bundlingOptions := &awscdklambdagoalpha.BundlingOptions{
    GoBuildFlags: &[]*string{jsii.String(`-ldflags "-s -w" -tags lambda.norpc`)},
}

// creating the aws lambda
handler := awscdklambdagoalpha.NewGoFunction(stack, jsii.String("Function"), &awscdklambdagoalpha.GoFunctionProps{
    Architecture: awslambda.Architecture_ARM_64(),
    Entry:        jsii.String("../api/getitems/lambda"),
    Environment:  &map[string]*string{"DYNAMODB_TABLENAME": table.TableName()},
    Bundling:     bundlingOptions,
    MemorySize:   jsii.Number(1024),
    Timeout:      awscdk.Duration_Millis(jsii.Number(15000)),
})

// grant dynamodb read write permissions to the lambda
table.GrantReadWriteData(handler)
```

I am confused. Anyone any ideas why I get that error message when trying to run a `Scan` on the DynamoDB table?

**UPDATE**

Here is a screenshot of the Permissions tab on my Lambda:

[image: lambda permissions]

If I then click the link to the Execution Role associated with the Lambda, I get:

[image]

As you can see, it has the right permissions!

Comment: What is in your `personal` profile that you're using to deploy with?

Comment: Just my `.aws` config, here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/GR5Za4m.png) with sensitive info hidden.

Comment: Whatever is in the first red box is important - please hide the values but keep the keys there

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The keys are present, I've just hidden them cause I don't want my AWS access and secrets keys exposed. If you're referring to the red box in the `.aws/config`, then that is just hiding some other profiles. None of my profiles are named `default` if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: What keys do you have under the `personal` profile?

Comment: If you look at the permissions in the actual Lambda function, what do you see?

Comment: Are you trying to obfuscate the account numbers in the error messages? It seems odd that given the code you shared the lambda would be assuming a role in account '77744448697' but your table is in account '777650698697'. Also, can you share your handler's code?

Comment: What version of the CDK are you using?

Comment: @MatthewBonig ah so this is what Ermiya was getting at. Yep, I did "try" to obfuscate the account number, it looks like I failed too. I've now updated the question to show the actual error message without obfuscating anything.

Comment: Could you add the entire IAM policy of your lambda's role to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AWS region is different on the error log you provided and on the IAM role. The region on the error is **us-west-2** but the region on the role permissions is **eu-west-2**.

It seems that you hardcoded the region on your lambda handler in /main/api/getitems/handler.go line 31.

Comment: Wow, a good spot @Angelos. Thank you! It [now works](https://imgur.com/9GePSAw)! I feel really silly.